# Mac OS X Java SDK Support

Tags: java, macos

Can anyone tell me, or send me to a page, that can tell me what version of Java that a Mac OS X supports out of the box? I know for instance 10.5 comes with Java 1.5 installed by default. what about 10.4? 10.3? 10.2? 10.1?

My app needs to be cross platform and I need to figure out what Java version to use to build my Java code. This would also determine what versions of Mac OS X i can support, and i obviously want to support back as far as i can.

I initially compiled using Java 1.6 and tried to run on my test machine - Mac OS X 10.4.11 (and it crashed of course). So it looks like Java 1.6 is completely out because 10.4 cannot support it at all even fully updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this document](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2002/tn2110.html), specifically the **Java Version Strings** section. I don't think there's a one-to-one relationship between Mac OS X versions and Java versions.